# Cartesian Product of Lists Using Ada

Tags: ada

I am currently working on programming this (https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_two_or_more_lists) in Ada, I am trying to do a Cartesian product between different sets. I need help figuring it out, the main issue is how would I be able to declare empty Pairs and calculate that if it's empty, then the result should be empty. Thank you!

Numbers I am trying to use:

```
{1, 2} × {3, 4}
{3, 4} × {1, 2}
{1, 2} × {}
{} × {1, 2}
```

My code:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO; -- Basically importing the functions that will be used to print out the results.

procedure Hello is -- Procedure is where variables & functions are declared!
    type T_Pair is array(1..2) of Integer; -- Declare a type of array that contains a set of 2 numbers (Used for final result!).
    type T_Result is array(1..4) of T_Pair; -- Declare a type of array that contains a set of T_Pair(s), used to hold the result.

    Demo1 : T_Result;
    Demo1A : T_Pair := (1, 2);
    Demo1B : T_Pair := (3, 4);


    function Fun_CartProd(p1: T_Pair; p2: T_Pair) return T_Result is
        results: T_Result;
        i: integer := 1;
    begin
        for j in 1..2 loop
            for h in 1..2 loop
                results(i) := (p1(j), p2(h));
                i := i + 1;
            end loop;
        end loop;
        return results;
    end Fun_CartProd;
begin -- This is where the statements go
    Demo1 := Fun_CartProd(Demo1A, Demo1B);
    for K in 1 .. Demo1'length loop
        Put(" [");
        for B in 1 .. Demo1(K)'length loop
            Put(Integer'Image(Demo1(K)(B)));
            if Demo1(K)'length /= B then
                Put(",");
            end if;
        end loop;
        Put("]");
        if Demo1'length /= K then
            Put(",");
        end if;
    end loop;
    Put_Line(""); -- Create a new line.
end Hello;
```

Comment: You don't say which part you are having trouble with (picking a type to represent your inputs/outputs, the algorithm itself, some trouble with compiler errors,etc).  Can you clarify what specifically you need help on?  Also, are all your inputs always the same size or do you need to worry about inputs with different sizes?

Comment: @Jere Sorry about that, I have clarified the issue much better now and I have also updated the code. I am basically confused on how to declare and calculate empty pairs and how to account for sets that have more than 2 numbers, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since each set of integers can be any length, including empty, I would start with a type that can handle all those situations:

```ada
type Integer_Set is array(Positive range <>) of Integer; -- Input type
type Integer_Tuple is array(Positive range <>_ of Integer; -- Output type
```

and you can represent the empty sets and tuples this way:

```ada
Empty_Set : constant Integer_Set(1..0) := (others => <>);
Empty_Tuple : constant Integer_Tuple(1..0) := (others => <>);
```

The other problem isn't just how many elements are in each set, but how many sets you will be finding the product of.  For this I would recommend some kind of container.  An array won't work here because each of the individual sets can have different sizes (including empty), but Ada has a variety of "indefinite" containers that can handle that.  Here is an example using vectors:

```ada
package Set_Vectors is new Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Vectors
   (Index_Type   => Positive,
    Element_Type => Integer_Set);
package Tuple_Vectors is new Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Vectors
   (Index_Type   => Positive,
    Element_Type => Integer_Tuple);
```

and you can then represent an empty result as:

```ada
Empty_Tuple_Vector : constant Tuple_Vectors.Vector := Tupler_Vectors.Empty_Vector;
```

Now you can create a function that takes in a vector of sets and returns a Cartesian product which will also be a vector of sets:

```ada
function Cartesian_Product(Inputs : Set_Vectors.Vector) return Tuple_Vectors.Vector;
```

If one of the input sets is empty, you return an Empty_Tuple_Vector.  You can check if one of the input sets are empty by checking their Length attribute result.  It will be 0 if they are empty.  Additionally if the input vector is completely empty, you can decide to either return Empty_Tuple_Vector or raise an exception.  For example:

```ada
if Inputs'Length = 0 then
   return Empty_Tuple_Vector;  -- or raise an exception, etc.
end if;

for Set of Inputs loop
   if Set'Length = 0 then
      return Empty_Tuple_Vector;
   end if;
   -- Maybe do other stuff here if you need
end loop;
```

Note that the logic you presented assumes only pairs of inputs.  I don't have enough experience to convert your logic to account for variable inputs, but perhaps someone can comment on that if you need it.

Also note as Flyx commented, this does not semantically check if a set is a set or not on the inputs (I.E. no duplicate values).

Comment: The types of the function signature `Cartesian_Product` are *able* to contain the correct data, however they are not semantically correct. The return type is a set of tuples, not a vector of sets. In detail, a *set* should not be able to contain the same element multiple times, but the tuples in the return value are able to, so they shouldn't be stored in a type named `Integer_Set`.

Comment: @flyx I added some different return types and a note at the bottom about semantic checking of sets.

Comment: My knowledge of Ada is to low to fully understand how to implement most of the answer, but I just wanted to thank you for taking the time to help me!